# Use special characters inside perl script for system calls

Tags: perl, path, environment-variables

I'm writing a short installation script in Perl that sets up the user's environmental variables to find certain libraries.  I'm using the `system()` function to set the `$PATH` variable.  However, since that requires the use of the special character `$`, Perl doesn't like it.

```
system("export PATH=$PATH:/library/directory/here");
```

That doesn't do anything because it tries to replace `$PATH`.  When I escape the dollar sign like so:

```
system("export PATH=\$PATH:/library/directory/here");
```

that doesn't work either.

What can I do?

Comment: You can't set the user's environment from inside a perl script. Basically Perl runs it's own shell processes. See here: http://bit.ly/h0vefS (sorry for the shortened URL, it goes to the Perl FAQ)

Comment: system command forks out of parent process.

Comment: Cfreak: http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#I_changed_directory_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update PATH system variable, use this:

```
$ENV{'PATH'}.=':/library/directory/here';
```

After this **/library/directory/here** will be available through PATH for this and all forked processes:

```
...
system("echo old PATH=$PATH");
$ENV{'PATH'}.=':/library/directory/here';
system("echo new PATH=$PATH");
...
```

Comment: Does this replace the $PATH variable or just update it? I'd prefer the latter, obviously :)

Comment: This will still only affect children of the perl process. Better than the `system` variant, which does nothing at all, but still probably not what's wanted :)

Comment: @yavoh This will update $PATH (that dot (.) is a concatenation) and will be available for all forked process (using system() or backtick op), i.e. inside this script - which as I understand enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

*NIX, unlike Windows, has a separate environment for every process.  When you set the PATH via system, it changes it in the sub-process.  But then the system command is done, so the its environment is deleted as part of the process clean-up.

Setting the PATH via ENV will set it of the Perl script and all processes forked off of it.  It will **NOT** set the PATH in the shell that runs the script.  That has to be done separately via the `source` command for csh and the dot command, '.', for bash.  See `man bash` for details.

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes e.g

```
my $cmd = 'export PATH=$PATH:/library/directory/here';
system($cmd);
```

Alternatively you can create a bash script that exports PATH variable. 
You might also consider to use full path of the script that you trying to call from the Perl instead of calling the program by its name only e.g. use /usr/env/perl instead of perl.

Comment: It still won't set the user's path.

Comment: Ibrahim is right.  Is there any way to mark a comment as having the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

When using double quotes in perl, it replaces variables within the string. Using single quotes perl will not interpret the $ within it.

Comment: Good to know! This is what I get for my ad-hoc approach to learning new languages.  Thanks :)